# run system command using system() inside shiny-server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny app which needs to run system commands to trigger a data integration job through a call to system(), if i run stand-alone shiny(running with runApp) this works fine, however if i deploy the code to shiny-server without changes the system() command do not work . Is system() a valid call inside shiny server? If not, what alternatives are there to execute system commands ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone get in this situation ,i found my problem was because shiny-server runs under "shiny" user which did not have privileges to run the system command i needed(run some scripts) and also did not have privileges(read nor execute) to the scripts, it was fixed by granting the necesary rights to the "shiny" user.

Answer (score 1):

Running `system()` in shiny (& shiny-server) works just fine:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
textOutput("dirOut")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  SysName <- Sys.info()['sysname']

  if(SysName=="Linux"){
    dir <- system("pwd", intern = TRUE)
  } else if(SysName=="Windows"){
    dir <- system("cmd cd", intern = TRUE)
  } else {
    dir <- paste("Error: No cmd given for", SysName)
  }

   output$dirOut <- renderText({
     dir
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: it's not working for me in shiy-server, but works if i run the app in stand-alone shiny, i'm guessing is related to the "shiny" user which is used to run the server not having permissions.

Comment: Yes, might be it's a permissions thing.

Comment: Have a look at this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/shiny-discuss/rSMsQ662vrg especially  Joe Cheng's answer